# Create sorting group ID without sorting the group

Tags: string, sorting, stata

I would like to create a sorting group ID without sorting the group.

`var1` is my variable of interest and contains some random values. `id_1` is a unique ID based on _n of `var1`. `group` contains information on the group that the respective `var1` observation belongs to. Note that the strings in `group` do not contain any sorting information, meaning that there is no value in sorting alphabetically.

I would like to create `id_group` because, in a next step, I would like to collapse `var1` by `group` without losing the sorting of the `group`. If I simply `collapse(max) var1, by(group)`, Stata will sort the results by `group` alphabetically - which I do not want. I would like to create `id_group` to then `collapse(max) var1, by(id_group)` and maintain the order of the groups.

I have tried to work with `bysort` but this command sorts `group` alphabetically to create a new ID. `egen` does not work either because the created IDs are not in a sorted order.

```
clear
input   var1  id_var1 str6 group id_group
    3       1       "C"    1
    1       2       "C"    1
    9       3       "C"    1
    5       4       "A"    2
    3       5       "B"    3
    0       6       "F"    4
    9       7       "Z"    5 
    1       8       "Y"    6
    3       9       "T"    7
    2       10      "T"    7
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
clear
input   var1  id_var1 str6 group id_group
    3       1       "C"    1
    1       2       "C"    1
    9       3       "C"    1
    5       4       "A"    2
    3       5       "B"    3
    0       6       "F"    4
    9       7       "Z"    5 
    1       8       "Y"    6
    3       9       "T"    7
    2       10      "T"    7
end

gen wanted = sum(group != group[_n-1]) 

list , sepby(wanted) 

     +--------------------------------------------+
     | var1   id_var1   group   id_group   wanted |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  1. |    3         1       C          1        1 |
  2. |    1         2       C          1        1 |
  3. |    9         3       C          1        1 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  4. |    5         4       A          2        2 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  5. |    3         5       B          3        3 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  6. |    0         6       F          4        4 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  7. |    9         7       Z          5        5 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  8. |    1         8       Y          6        6 |
     |--------------------------------------------|
  9. |    3         9       T          7        7 |
 10. |    2        10       T          7        7 |
     +--------------------------------------------+
```